# How to lazy load a react component

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I need to build a home page and I want the h1 and p to be rendered first and if the user scroll to the area of MyComponent, MyComponnet gets rendered or the async call in MyComponent does not prevent h1 or p rendering so that to have a better user experience. Is there a way I can do it?

```
const Home = () => {
return <div>
 <h1>Home Page</h1>
 <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
 <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
 <p>aaaaaaaaaa</p>
 <MyComponent />
</div>;
}


const MyComponent = () => {
 const res = await fetch('some url...');
 // ... some code process the res
 const data = processRes(res);
 return <div>data</div> 
}
```

Comment: Set a loading state whenever you start the fetch and then set that state to false after it completes or fails.  *After* the hooks, put an early return that will show "loading" or something else if that loading state is still true and then return the real component after the state is set to false.  Or wait for [`React.suspense`](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html) to be finished which encapsulates the pattern for you in a "React aware" way.

Answer (score 1):

React is evolving for such use cases for enhanced experience and currently it's in experimental phase.

https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-intro.html

Having said that, yours can be achieved with minor changes.

```
const MyComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./MyComponent')); // load lazy
return (
<>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>  
  <Suspense fallback={<SplashScreen/>}>
    <MyComponent/>
  </Suspense>
</>);
```